# Order table by row alphabeticaly

Tags: tables, sorting

I have a table like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,spanish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{selinput}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\SelectInputMappings{%
  aacute={á},
  ntilde={ñ},
  Euro={€}
}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage [left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{| p{.15\textwidth} | p{.85\textwidth} |} 
\hline
Spanish     & English                                       \\ \hline
ser         & to be (essential/permanent quality)           \\ \hline
haber       & to have (to do something, auxiliary verb)     \\ \hline
estar       & to be (health, location, state)               \\ \hline
tener       & to have                                       \\ \hline
hacer       & to do, make                                   \\ \hline
poder       & to be able, can                               \\ \hline
decir       & to say, tell                                  \\ \hline
ir          & to go                                         \\ \hline
ver         & to see                                        \\ \hline
dar         & to give                                       \\ \hline
saber       & to know (information)                         \\ \hline
querer      & to want, love                                 \\ \hline
llegar      & to arrive, come, reach                        \\ \hline
pasar       & to pass, to spend (time), to happen           \\ \hline
deber       & to owe, must, should, ought to                \\ \hline
poner       & to put, place, set                            \\ \hline
parecer     & to seem, appear                               \\ \hline
quedar      & to stay, remain                               \\ \hline
creer       & to believe                                    \\ \hline
hablar      & to speak                                      \\ \hline
llevar      & to carry, bring                               \\ \hline
dejar       & to leave, abandon, to let, allow              \\ \hline
seguir      & to follow, continue                           \\ \hline
encontrar   & to find, encounter                            \\ \hline
llamar      & to call, to name                              \\ \hline
% About 1500 rows more
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I am alway add in this table new words. I would like to order automatically rows by the value of the `Spanish`column on alphabetical order (A-Z).

I really like how it was made [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264418/order-table-by-row). I tried to do the same for my table but I failed.

Could you help me please?

Comment: I would select the lines and then use the "tools->sort lines" option of my editor (winedt). Faster than sorting with tex.

Comment: I am using online editor (overleaf) and there isn't this option. Also I'd like be able to do it with tex. Anyway thank you for your comment.

Comment: TeX isn't very good at sorting; that's why BibTeX and biber were created: to sort bibliographic entries alphabetically. (Well, LuaLaTeX offers access to Lua's `table` functions, including `table.sort`. However, using LuaLaTeX would seem like overkill for what you say you want to achieve.) You may want to look into (a) placing the tabular material -- *without* the `\hline` stuff -- in a csv file, (b) using an external program to sort the material on the first column, and (c) employing something like the `csvsimple` package to place the tabular material inside a `longtable` environment.

Comment: You may also wish to look into the capabilities of the `datatool` package. It can perform sorting, which the `csvsimple` package does not. The downside is that learning how to use `datatool` efficiently will take a bit more effort than does loading `csvsimple`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Mico. It seems very difficult for me now. I am really new at Latex. And all I wanted is just sort my table in online editor (overleaf). As I wrote before I like the solution from the question №264418. It works great, but I just couldn't reproduce it for my table. Hovewer, I am looking forward that some day I will be able to understand things which you described :)

Comment: Your example uses only ascii. This is rather easy to sort alphabetically. But add to @egreg's code `\spanishverb{árbol}{tree}` and look what happen (with and without utf8+inputenc). If your example stay so simple you can use his code, but if words with accents etc are involved too it would be better to use some tool which has the relevant unicode libraries like biber.

Comment: You could use `glossaries`, I think. (With `xindy`, you could also sort with non-ASCII.) Or some other wrapper for `makeindex` or `xindy`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A proof of concept, using an idea from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356777/4427

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\spanishverb}{mm}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_alex_spanishverbs_seq { \__alex_spanishverbs_entry:nn {#1}{#2} }
 }

\seq_new:N \g_alex_spanishverbs_seq
\tl_new:N  \g__alex_spanishverbs_tablebody_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\sortverbs}{}
 {
  \cs_gset_eq:NN \__alex_spanishverbs_entry:nn \use_i:nn
  \seq_gsort:Nn \g_alex_spanishverbs_seq
   {
    \alex_spanishverbs_if_before:ffTF { ##1 } { ##2 }
     { \sort_return_same: }
     { \sort_return_swapped: }
   }
  \cs_gset_eq:NN \__alex_spanishverbs_entry:nn \alex_spanishverbs_print:nn
  \tl_gset:Nx \g__alex_spanishverbs_tablebody_tl
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \g_alex_spanishverbs_seq { \\ \hline }
   }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\printverbs}{}
 {
  \tl_use:N \g__alex_spanishverbs_tablebody_tl
 }

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \alex_spanishverbs_if_before:nn { p,T,F,TF }
 {% I hope the LaTeX3 police won't catch me
  \int_compare:nTF { \pdftex_strcmp:D { #1 } { #2 } < 0 }
   {
    \prg_return_true:
   }
   {
    \prg_return_false:
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \alex_spanishverbs_if_before:nnTF { ff }

\cs_new:Nn \alex_spanishverbs_print:nn { #1 & #2 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\spanishverb{ser}{to be (essential/permanent quality)}
\spanishverb{haber}{to have (to do something, auxiliary verb)}
\spanishverb{estar}{to be (health, location, state)}
\spanishverb{tener}{to have}
\spanishverb{hacer}{to do, make}
\spanishverb{poder}{to be able, can}
\spanishverb{decir}{to say, tell}
\spanishverb{ir}{to go}
\spanishverb{ver}{to see}
\spanishverb{dar}{to give}
\spanishverb{saber}{to know (information)}
\spanishverb{querer}{to want, love}
\spanishverb{llegar}{to arrive, come, reach}
\spanishverb{pasar}{to pass, to spend (time), to happen}
\spanishverb{deber}{to owe, must, should, ought to}
\spanishverb{poner}{to put, place, set}
\spanishverb{parecer}{to seem, appear}
\spanishverb{quedar}{to stay, remain}
\spanishverb{creer}{to believe}
\spanishverb{hablar}{to speak}
\spanishverb{llevar}{to carry, bring}
\spanishverb{dejar}{to leave, abandon, to let, allow}
\spanishverb{seguir}{to follow, continue}
\spanishverb{encontrar}{to find, encounter}
\spanishverb{llamar}{to call, to name}
\sortverbs

\begin{longtable}{
 |
 p{\dimexpr.15\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}
 |
 p{\dimexpr.85\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}
 |
} 
\hline
Spanish & English \\ \hline
\printverbs \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could replace `\pdftex_strcmp:D ` by `\__str_if_eq_x:nn`, then it would work with luatex too. But there seem to be no public function to test if the result is positive or negative.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Using either is the same: both are “forbidden”. I believe that one day there will be an alphabetical sorter in `expl3`, but you can understand what the problems are: different collating orders, for instance, and accented characters. Probably this particular problem should be delegated to Python or similar scripting language.

Comment: Yes I know that both are forbidden. But as the second works with all engines I think as a forbidden fruit it is better. And I understand the sorting problems, that's why I suggested in my comment directly to use an external tool.

Comment: @egreg Thanks a lot for your answer. It seems great! Unfortunadly, it doesn't work for me. I am using online editor (overleaf). And when I try to reproduce your code there, appears an error: `Undefined control sequence.
l.30 \NewExpandableDocumentCommand
                                  {\printverbs}{} ` on the line №30: `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\printverbs}{}`. Could you help me please with it? What am I doing wrong? What should I do?

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately, Overleaf lags behind in updates

Comment: @egreg Ah, I got it. What soft do you recommend me to use _[to be able to use your code]_?

Comment: @Alex Actually, I suggest you use an external scripting program for 1500+ items.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your comments. I gonna close the question.

Answer (score 5):

R/Sweave/knitr approach:

1) The table content is an easy to make `SPUK.csv` file, with this format:

```
Spanish    ; English                                       
ser        ; to be (essential/permanent quality)           
haber      ; to have (to do something, auxiliary verb)     
estar      ; to be (health, location, state) 
...
```

2) Then is fairly simple in R read it as a data frame, sort it, and print the data frame as a LaTeX table with `xtable` library.

For a long table with headers on every page, you will need play with  some options (not so easy, I admit) but here a R code that does this:

```
library(xtable)
options(xtable.booktabs = T)
SPUK <- read.table("SPUK.csv", header=T, sep=";")
add.to.row <- list(pos = list(0), command =NULL )
command <- paste0("\\midrule\n\\endhead\n",
"\\bottomrule\n",
"{\\footnotesize Continued on next page}\n",
"\\endfoot\n",
"\\endlastfoot\n")
add.to.row$command <- command

print(xtable(SPUK[order(SPUK$Spanish),] , 
      caption = "Spanish verbs"), 
      caption.placement = "top",
      add.to.row = add.to.row,
      tabular.environment = "longtable", 
      include.colnames = T,
      floating = F, include.rownames = F)
```

If the result is 100% satisfactory, and you do not need make any any modification, using `knitr` you do not need to enter in R each time, then copy & paste the result in the LaTeX document. It will be enough insert the above code in the LateX code only one time:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
<<xxx, results="asis", echo=F>>=
library(xtable)
options(xtable.booktabs = T)
SPUK <- read.table("SPUK.csv", header=T, sep=";")
add.to.row <- list(pos = list(0), command =NULL )
command <- paste0("\\midrule\n\\endhead\n",
"\\bottomrule\n",
"{\\footnotesize Continued on next page}\n",
"\\endfoot\n",
"\\endlastfoot\n")
add.to.row$command <- command
print(xtable(SPUK[order(SPUK$Spanish),] , 
      caption = "Spanish verbs"), 
      caption.placement = "top",
      add.to.row = add.to.row,
      tabular.environment = "longtable", 
      include.colnames = T,
      floating = F, include.rownames = F)   
@

\lipsum[4-5]
\end{document}
```

If you do not know how compile this with `knitr`, save it as `filename.Rnw`, open it with Rstudio and push the <kbd>Compile PDF</kbd> buttom. Result:

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you read two papers by the (unfortunately) late Kees van der Laan, viz "Sorting in BLUe" (https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/64ed/fe77b0760edc9bc8169087665795efd5505e.pdf) and "Sorting within TeX" (https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb14-3/tb40laan-sort.pdf). Both contain rich ideas and lots of macros for sorting numbers, words or whatever using TeX, but be warned that their contents is rather technical and needs very, very  careful reading !