# How to arrange tabular in alphabetical order

Tags: tables, alphabet

I have this code, which I want to arrange in alphabetical order:

```
\section{Abbreviations} 
\doublespacing
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{12cm}}
\textbf{AD}  & Alzheimer's disease \\
\textbf{FAD}  & Familial Alzheimer's disease \\
\textbf{LOAD}  & Late-onset Alzheimer's disease \\
\textbf{A\textbeta\ }  & Amyloid- \textbeta\  \\
\textbf{APP}  & Amyloid precursor protein \\
\textbf{GWAS}  & Genome-wide-association studies \\
\textbf{SNP}  & Single nucleotide polymorphisms \\
\textbf{CXCL10}  & C-X-C motif chemokine 10 \\
\textbf{OAS1}  & 2’-5’-oligoadenylate synthase 1\\
\textbf{TREM2}  & Triggering receptor expressed on myeloid cells 2 \\
\textbf{R47H KI}  & \textit{Trem2} R47H knock-in mice \\
\textbf{APP KI}  & \textit{APP\textsuperscript{NL-G-F}} knock-in mice \\
\textbf{WT}  & Wild type  \\
\textbf{HO}  & Homozygous \\
\textbf{HET}  & Heterozygous \\
\textbf{P1-P3}  & Postnatal day 1-3\\
\textbf{RT-qPCR}  & Real-time Quantitative PCR  \\
\textbf{CT}  & Cycle threshold \\
\textbf{IHC}  & Immunohistochemistry \\
\textbf{PBS}  & Phosphate-buffered saline \\
\textbf{PBST}  & Phosphate-buffered saline 0.3\% Triton \\
\textbf{TBS}  & Tris-buffered saline \\
\textbf{TBST}  & Tris-buffered saline 0.1\% Tween-20 \\
\end{tabular}
```

How can I do that? Help is hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This question is a duplicate of this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/372603/138900 do you agree with that?

Answer (score 4):

First, remove all `\textbf{}`. Load [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) and use the command `>{\bfseries}` to make the first column boldface.

Thereafter, see if your text editor has a line sorting function, mark all the lines that you want to sort, and sort them. If not, copy the lines to a word processor or spreadsheet, or save the lines as a text file and pipe it through a the sort filter at your operating system command prompt (Windowds command line `sort < tobesort.txt > sorted.txt`), and sort.

You have to check the ISO sorting rules for you language to decide where to place the Greek letter. In Norwegian, the `Aβ` was sorted as the last line starting with `A`.

Unless you have tens of similar tabulars to sort, this approach is the simplest and fastest, if not someone provide a sorting algorithm that can sort according to your language requirements.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\section{Abbreviations} 

\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}p{4cm}p{12cm}@{}}
AD  & Alzheimer's disease \\
APP  & Amyloid precursor protein \\
APP KI  & \textit{APP\textsuperscript{NL-G-F}} knock-in mice \\
A\boldmath{$\beta$}\   & Amyloid-$\beta$\  \\
CT  & Cycle threshold \\
CXCL10  & C-X-C motif chemokine 10 \\
FAD  & Familial Alzheimer's disease \\
GWAS  & Genome-wide-association studies \\
HET  & Heterozygous \\
HO  & Homozygous \\
IHC  & Immunohistochemistry \\
LOAD  & Late-onset Alzheimer's disease \\
OAS1  & 2’-5’-oligoadenylate synthase 1\\
P1-P3  & Postnatal day 1-3\\
PBS  & Phosphate-buffered saline \\
PBST  & Phosphate-buffered saline 0.3\% Triton \\
R47H KI  & \textit{Trem2} R47H knock-in mice \\
RT-qPCR  & Real-time Quantitative PCR  \\
SNP  & Single nucleotide polymorphisms \\
TBS  & Tris-buffered saline \\
TBST  & Tris-buffered saline 0.1\% Tween-20 \\
TREM2  & Triggering receptor expressed on myeloid cells 2 \\
WT  & Wild type  \\

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```