# Sorting tables alphabetically

Tags: tables, sorting, automation

I want to write a document with a couple tables, where the entries of the tables are sorted alphabetically. I found a solution here:

[Order table by row alphabeticaly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372603/order-table-by-row-alphabetically)

But when I want more than one table in my document, the entries of previous tables are also used in the new table. How can I alter the code, such that I can have more than one table in the document?

Here a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xparse}     

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\name}{mmm}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_alex_name_seq { \__alex_name_entry:nn {#1}{#2}{#3} }
 }
\seq_new:N \g_alex_name_seq
\tl_new:N  \g__alex_name_tablebody_tl

\NewDocumentCommand{\sortnames}{}
 {
  \cs_gset_eq:NN \__alex_name_entry:nn \use_i:nn
  \seq_gsort:Nn \g_alex_name_seq
   {
    \alex_name_if_before:ffTF { ##1 } { ##2 }
     { \sort_return_same: }
     { \sort_return_swapped: }
   }
  \cs_gset_eq:NN \__alex_name_entry:nn \alex_name_print:nn
  \tl_gset:Nx \g__alex_name_tablebody_tl
   {
    \seq_use:Nn \g_alex_name_seq { \\ \hline }
   }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\printnames}{}
 {
  \tl_use:N \g__alex_name_tablebody_tl
 }

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \alex_name_if_before:nn { p,T,F,TF }
 {% I hope the LaTeX3 police won't catch me
  \int_compare:nTF { \pdftex_strcmp:D { #1 } { #2 } < 0 }
   {
    \prg_return_true:
   }
   {
    \prg_return_false:
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \alex_name_if_before:nnTF { ff }

\cs_new:Nn \alex_name_print:nn { #1 & #2 &  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%First Table
\name{Jerimir}{Some Project}{B}
\name{Emma}{Second Project }{A}
\sortnames
\begin{longtable}{
 |
 p{\dimexpr.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}
 |
 p{\dimexpr.6\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}
 |
 p{\dimexpr.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}
 |
} 
\hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Project} & Grade\\ \hline
\printnames \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

% Second Table
\name{Aaro}{New Project}{A}
\name{Zion}{Other Project}{C}
\sortnames
\begin{longtable}{
 |
 p{\dimexpr.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}
 |
 p{\dimexpr.6\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}
 |
 p{\dimexpr.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}
 |
} 
\hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Project} & Grade  \\ \hline
\printnames \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The names of the first table are also in the second table:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Unfortunately, it's impossible for us to tell you how to alter the code where we don't have the code you're using.  Please post a minimal working example.

Comment: The question now includes a minimal working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use LuaLaTeX, the following could work. As you can see, `\sortnames` is no longer necessary. Moreover, the name list cleans itself with each print and you only need the first `\hline` (although you can include it into the Lua macro if you want)

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{luacode} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{xparse}     
\begin{luacode*}
    nametable = nametable or {}
    function addnames(A, B, C)
        table.insert(nametable, A..[[ & ]]..B..[[ & ]]..C..[[\\ \hline ]])
    end

    function clearnames(table)
        for k in pairs (table) do
            table [k] = nil
        end
    end
\end{luacode*}
\def\name#1#2#3{\directlua{addnames("#1", "#2", "#3")}}
\def\printnames{%
    \directlua{
    table.sort(nametable) 
    tex.sprint(table.concat(nametable," "))
    clearnames(nametable)
    }
}
\begin{document}
%First Table
\name{Jerimir}{Some Project}{B}
\name{Emma}{Second Project }{A}

\begin{longtable}{
 |
 p{\dimexpr.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}
 |
 p{\dimexpr.6\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}
 |
 p{\dimexpr.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}
 |
} 
\hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Project} & Grade\\ \hline
\printnames 
\end{longtable}

% Second Table
\name{Aaro}{New Project}{A}
\name{Zion}{Other Project}{C}

\begin{longtable}{
 |
 p{\dimexpr.2\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}
 |
 p{\dimexpr.6\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}
 |
 p{\dimexpr.1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}
 |
} 
\hline
\textbf{Name} & \textbf{Project} & Grade  \\ \hline
\printnames
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]